# json async load msgs first 15 then at the end of the list load 15 more and so on.. till the end

Tags: android, json, asynchronous

I have async listview where json is parsed and displayed in the list.

1.I would like to load 15 msgs first.
2.At the end Of the list there should be a footer
3.After clicking on the footer or after reaching the footer it should load next 15 msgs from different url not the first url.

How Do I load next 15 msgs in the same list-but from different url this time in async.

Links I have referred till now : http://p-xr.com/android-tutorial-how-to-parse-read-json-data-into-a-android-listview/

Attaching the code :

```
public class btn extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    SimpleAdapter adapter;
    JSONArray  earthquakes;
    String jString;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist;
    String magni;
    ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listplaceholder);
        mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


        new loadsomestuff().execute();




    }

    public class loadsomestuff extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{


        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pd=new ProgressDialog(btn.this);
            pd.setTitle("Loading......Please wait");
            pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            pd.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            jString="{\"earthquakes\": [{ \"eqid\": \"c0001xgp\", \"magnitude\": 8.8, \"lng\": 142.369, \"src\": \"us\", \"datetime\": \"2011-03-11 04:46:23\", \"depth\": 24.4,\"lat\": 38.322 },{ \"eqid\": \"2007hear\",\"magnitude\": 8.4,\"lng\": 101.3815,\"src\": \"us\", \"datetime\": \"2007-09-12 09:10:26\",\"depth\": 30,\"lat\": -4.5172},{ \"eqid\": \"2007hear\",\"magnitude\": 8.5,\"lng\": 101.3815,\"src\": \"us\", \"datetime\": \"2007-09-12 09:10:26\",\"depth\": 30,\"lat\": -4.5172},{ \"eqid\": \"2007hear\",\"magnitude\": 8.6,\"lng\": 101.3815,\"src\": \"us\", \"datetime\": \"2007-09-12 09:10:26\",\"depth\": 30,\"lat\": -4.5172},{ \"eqid\": \"2007hear\",\"magnitude\": 8.7,\"lng\": 101.3815,\"src\": \"us\", \"datetime\": \"2007-09-12 09:10:26\",\"depth\": 30,\"lat\": -4.5172}]}";
            //   JSONObject  json=JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(jString);
            JSONObject jObject = null;
            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jString);
            } catch (JSONException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } 
            try{

                earthquakes = jObject.getJSONArray("earthquakes");

                for(int i=0;i<earthquakes.length();i++){                        
                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();    
                    JSONObject e = earthquakes.getJSONObject(i);

                    magni= e.getString("magnitude");


                    map.put("id",  String.valueOf(i));
                    map.put("name", "Earthquake name:" + e.getString("eqid"));
                    map.put("magnitude", "Magnitude: " +  e.getString("magnitude"));
                    mylist.add(map);

                    publishProgress(((int) ((i / (float) earthquakes.length()) * 100)));
                }   
                adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), mylist , R.layout.main, 
                        new String[] { "name", "magnitude" }, 
                        new int[] { R.id.item_title, R.id.item_subtitle });

            }catch(JSONException e)        {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            }

            return null;
        }
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...integers) {

            pd.incrementProgressBy(integers[0]);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);


            setListAdapter(adapter);

            pd.dismiss();

            final ListView lv = getListView();
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);  
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {  
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                   
                    Toast.makeText(btn.this, "ID '" + o.get("id") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

                }
            });
        }



    }
}
```

Comment: It would be 15 first ,then add 15 more when he reaches the end of the list this should continue until all his messages from the server is displayed.So its a very long list.But this is the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download new messages, add them to your adapter's myList list and run notifyDataSetChanged() on your listView. Remember that changing adapter's data set (adding items to ArrayList, or just notifying the adapter) should be made in UI thread.

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I have used Onscroll item click and it gives me a toast at the end of the list.How do I show loading bar till it loads? should I use runnable function with progress dialog or Async can handle it for me?

Comment: You want loading bar on last item, or at front of the user?

Comment: I managed to make it work By having loading bar in front of the user,but the on scroll activity triggers multiple times how do I manage to trigger it only once? Thanks again.

Comment: Try to use some boolean variable that will tell if it was already triggered?